Making sense of 緻密かつ大胆、可愛らしさと迫力の同居する
From manga's あとがき,

緻密かつ大胆、可愛らしさと迫力の同居する作画により、「賭ケグルイ」を僕の脳内イメージを遥かに超える漫画に仕立てあげて下さっている尚村先生。

I am not sure about the structure of the clause 緻密かつ大胆、可愛らしさと迫力の同居する.
I know that 同居する here means to exist together as contradictory pairs. It appears to me that the contradictory pairs are 緻密+大胆 and 可愛らしさ+迫力 and there's right-node raising involved. So, 緻密かつ大胆が同居する and 可愛らしさと迫力が同居する are both modifying 作画. Is that right?

I agree that 緻密 vs 大胆 and 可愛らしさ vs 迫力 are both contradictory, but 緻密かつ大胆が同居する doesn't sound correct. This is because ① 緻密 and 大胆 are not nouns and ② you'd use と, rather than かつ, with 同居する. To make this phrase sound natural, I would say 緻密さと大胆さが同居する.
I'd parse that part as:
［緻密かつ大胆(で)］、［可愛らしさと迫力の同居する］作画
→　緻密かつ大胆な作画 + 可愛らしさと迫力の同居する作画
